Speeding up alr build with gtk
Is there a way of speeding up an alr build with gtk?  Say I start a new project.
alr init --bin a98xml
alr with gtk

That is simple enough.
alr build

This takes about 4 minutes.  We only have to do this once but it is 4 minutes for every project I get out of source code control.  Is it safe to do this once and then copy the alire/cache directory to all the projects?
I've tried it.  It seems to work but how safe is it?

If you can't find a lot of info here, there are alire communities at gitter and the ada-lang.io forums which are more active.  There is some crossover here (and I tagged your question with alire to hopefully get their attention), but it's a specific package manager that is independent from the language, so the number of folks who may be able to answer your question here might be limited.

If you’re using an up-to-date alr (I’m using 2.0.1, which isn’t the latest) you could check this setting (alr help settings):


dependencies.shared [Boolean][Default:TRUE]
When true, dependencies are downloaded and built in a shared location inside
the global cache. When false, dependencies are sandboxed in each workspace.


If true, release builds are cached (look in alr version for build folder) using some long hash. I don’t know what makes up the hash, it’ll be some mix of compiler/flags used for the build.
I’m using aarch64-apple-darwin (Macbook Air M1), and I’ve noticed that using the default gprbuild some crates (e.g. langkit, libadalang) get rebuilt anyway.

I've got some reports of unexpected rebuilds, and I want to get to the bottom of it. If you happen to stumble into some simple reproducible cases on Linux, that will simplify the matter for me.

@Álex, Mac only, sorry! But will post an issue with what I’ve got. It’s actually on gprbuild, or at any rate the Alire/Github build, since my own build works fine -- where should I post?

Investigation here.

I'm using 1.2.1 on a chromebook.  There is no such option.  Looks like I'll have to update my version of alr.  I'll accept this as the answer in the mean time.
